# React Native "TypeError: Network request failed" on real devices (android)

Tags: android, react-native

It was working properly few days ago but suddenly it stopped working. When I'm trying to communicate with my development server "http://192.168.13.55:8000/" both IOS and Android emulators are working fine, but when I connect my phone, it's not working anymore.

I've tried adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on AndroidManifest.xml and also even tried commenting out

```
...
      NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
          new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
              // builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
            }
          });
...
```

on ReactNativeFlipper.java, deleted `node_modules` and still no luck

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 158.53 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.15.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.11.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.12.12.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/raybi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33
      Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0
      System Images: android-31 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401
    Xcode: 14.3.1/14E300c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.6 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.7 => 0.71.7 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Can anyone help me to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the device might not be able to access the local network like this.
Try using a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose the required port, and use it in the app, similar to any hosted server.

Comment: I know this. It worked with localtunnel. But my problem is, the method I mentioned it was working just a day before, but suddenly it stopped working. I want to know the reason why it isn't working anymore

Answer (score 0):

To Connect to the development server, you do following:
run the `adb` command to get the device name:

```bash
$ adb devices
```

then run:

```bash
adb -s <device name> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

In your react native code you replace `BASE_URL_MYSERVER = 'http://192.168.1.10:5185/api'`
where 192.168.1.10 is your PC's IP.
Note that you must allow USB debugging on the device.